# Cut first line from txt file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

In windows cmd (batch) what is the easiest way to cut the first line from file into clipboard?

```
findstr /V /R "^$" filename.txt
```

Outputs `Cannot open filename.txt`

Answer (score 1):

you have to do it in two steps:

a) get the first line of the file into a variable:

```
<file.txt set /p "line="
```

b) put the variable into the clipboard:

```
echo %line%|clip
```

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: Win 7 ultimate too, but tested with the xp

Comment: ah, ok. For Win XP `clip` is part of the ressource kit. Win7 should run.